# compare two fields from two different files using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files where I want to compare certain fields and produce the output

I have a variable as well

```
echo ${CURR_SNAP}
123
```

File1

```
DOMAIN1|USER1|LE1|ORG1|ACCES1|RSCTYPE1|RSCNAME1
DOMAIN2|USER2|LE2|ORG2|ACCES2|RSCTYPE2|RSCNAME2
DOMAIN3|USER3|LE3|ORG3|ACCES3|RSCTYPE3|RSCNAME3
DOMAIN4|USER4|LE4|ORG4|ACCES4|RSCTYPE4|RSCNAME4
```

File2

```
ORG1|PRGPATH1
ORG3|PRGPATH3
ORG5|PRGPATH5
ORG6|PRGPATH6
ORG7|PRGPATH7
```

The output I am expecting as below where the last column is CURR_SNAP value and the matching will be 4th column of File1 should be matched with 1st column of File2

```
DOMAIN1|USER1|LE1|ORG1|ACCES1|RSCTYPE1|123
DOMAIN3|USER3|LE3|ORG3|ACCES3|RSCTYPE3|123
```

I tried with the below code piece but looks like I am not doing it correctly

```
awk -v CURRSNAP="${CURR_SNAP}" '{FS="|"} NR==FNR {x[$0];next} {if(x[$1]==$4) print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5"|"$6"|"CURRSNAP}' File2 File1
```

Comment: This should give you some idea on how to get environment variable inn to `awk` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: That works; but still the if part is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
#! /bin/bash

CURR_SNAP="123"

awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -v curr_snap="$CURR_SNAP" '{
    if (FNR == NR)
    {
        # this stores the ORG* as an index
        # here you can store other values if needed
        orgs_arr[$1]=1 
    }
    else if (orgs_arr[$4] == 1)
    {
        # overwrite $7 to contain CURR_SNAP value
        $7=curr_snap
        print
    }
}' file2 file1
```

As in your expected output, you didn't output `RSCNAME*`, so I have overwritten `$7`(which is column for `RSCNAME*`) with `$CURR_SNAP`. If you want to display `RSCNAME*` column aswell, remove `$7=curr_snap` and change `print` statement to `print $0, curr_snap`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `awk` at all. This is what [join(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) is meant for (Plus `sed` to append the extra column:

```
$ join -14 -21 -t'|' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6 File1 File2 | sed "s/$/|${CURR_SNAP}/"
DOMAIN1|USER1|LE1|ORG1|ACCES1|RSCTYPE1|123
DOMAIN3|USER3|LE3|ORG3|ACCES3|RSCTYPE3|123
```

It does require that the files be sorted based on the common field, like your examples are.

Comment: the actual size of both of the files are in GBs', and when I tried the command it throws me error "join: file1 is not in sorted order"

Comment: @KoushikChandra Like I said, join does require that files be sorted. If yours aren't, consider editing your samples to reflect that. If using bash, zsh, etc. one easy way to sort them is `join other args <(sort -t'|' -k4,4 File1) <(sort -t'|' -k1,1 File2)`. Or sort them ahead of time if this is something that's going to be run frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk` with two-rules. For the first file (where `NR==FNR`), simply use string concatenation to append the fields `1 - (NF-1)` assigning the concatenated result to an array indexed by `$4`. Then for the second file (where `NR>FNR`) in rule two test if `array[$1]` has content and if so, output the array and append `"|"CURR_SNAP` (with `CURR_SNAP` shortened to `c` in the example below and array being `a`), e.g.

```
CURR_SNAP=123

awk -F'|' -v c="$CURR_SNAP" '
    NR==FNR {
        for (i=1;i<NF;i++)
            a[$4]=i>1?a[$4]"|"$i:a[$4]$1
    }
    NR>FNR {
        if(a[$1])
            print a[$1]"|"c
    }
' file1 file2
```

**Example Use/Output**

After setting the filenames to match yours, you can simply copy/middle-mouse-paste in your console to test, e.g.

```
$ awk -F'|' -v c="$CURR_SNAP" '
>     NR==FNR {
>         for (i=1;i<NF;i++)
>             a[$4]=i>1?a[$4]"|"$i:a[$4]$1
>     }
>     NR>FNR {
>         if(a[$1])
>             print a[$1]"|"c
>     }
> ' file1 file2
DOMAIN1|USER1|LE1|ORG1|ACCES1|RSCTYPE1|123
DOMAIN3|USER3|LE3|ORG3|ACCES3|RSCTYPE3|123
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.